# Is there a way to split a large file into chunks with random sizes?

Tags: bash, shell

I know you can split a file with `split`, but for test purposes I would like to split a large file into chunks whose sizes differ. Is this possible?

Alternatively, if the above-mentioned file is a zip, is there a way to split it into volumes of unequal sizes?

Any suggestions welcome! Thanks!

Comment: how many parts do you want to split into? and how different should they be?

Comment: Let's say a hundred parts, each varying from a few megs, to a about 150 mb at most.

Comment: you need the idea or running codes?

Comment: Preferably running code, but idea would also be welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you tagged the question only with shell. so I supposed you want to handle it only with shell script and those common linux command/tools.

As far as I know there is no existing tool/cmd can split file randomly. To split file, we can consider to use `split, dd`

Both tools support options like, how big (size) split-ed file should be or how many files do you want to split. let's say, we use dd/split first split your file into 500 parts, each file has same size. so we have:

```
foo.zip.001
foo.zip.002
foo.zip.003
...
foo.zip.500
```

then we take this file list as input, to do merge (cat). This step could be done by awk or shell script.

for example we can build a set of `cat` statements like:

```
cat foo.zip.001, foo.zip.002 > part1
cat foo.zip.003, foo.zip.004, foo.zip.005 > part2
cat foo.zip.006, foo.zip.007, foo.zip.008, foo.zip.009 > part3
....
```

run the generated cat statements, you got final `part1-n`, each part has different size.

for example like:

```
kent$  seq  -f'foo.zip.%g' 20|awk 'BEGIN{i=k=2}NR<i{s=s sprintf ("%s,",$0);next}{k++;i=(NR+k);print "cat "s$0" >part"k-2;s="" }'                                            
cat foo.zip.1,foo.zip.2 >part1
cat foo.zip.3,foo.zip.4,foo.zip.5 >part2
cat foo.zip.6,foo.zip.7,foo.zip.8,foo.zip.9 >part3
cat foo.zip.10,foo.zip.11,foo.zip.12,foo.zip.13,foo.zip.14 >part4
cat foo.zip.15,foo.zip.16,foo.zip.17,foo.zip.18,foo.zip.19,foo.zip.20 >part5
```

but how is the performance you have to test on your own...at least this should work for your requirement.

Comment: +1: Neat way, thanks! I'll give it a go. Performance-wise: it's not a problem really, as it will be a one-time generation. I'm just wondering how to approach it, if I would like to also have a fixed number of produced files in the end.

Answer (score 2):

So the general question that you're asking is: how can I compute `N` random integers that sum to `S`?  Specifically, `S` is the size of your file and `N` is how many smaller files that you want to break it into.

For example, assume that you want to split your file into 4 parts.  If `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are four random numbers, then:

```
a + b + c + d = X
a/X + b/X + c/X + d/X = 1
S*a/X + S*b/X + S*c/X + S*d/X = S
```

Giving us four random numbers that sum to `S`, the size of your file.

Which means you'd want to write a script that:

1. Computes `N` random numbers (any random numbers).
2. Computes `X` as the sum of those random numbers.
3. Multiplies each of those random numbers by `S/X` (and makes sure you're left with integers greater than 0 that sum to S)
4. Splits the original file into pieces using the generated random numbers as sizes, using whatever tool you want.

This is a little much for a shell script, but would be pretty straight forward in something like Perl.

Comment: Thanks for all the math. Quite helpful. I will accept Kent's solution though, as it is also an implementation (despite not covering the sizing part). Thanks!